# Using XSD recursively

Tags: xml, visual-studio, recursion, xsd

I have the following XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu_list id="0" name="menu de topo" url="">
  <item id="0.1" url="Default.aspx" name="português">
    <item id="99" url="" name="apresentação">
      <item id="114" url="Menu.aspx?id=1000" name="mensagem da reitora">
      </item>
      <item id="151" url="" name="missão" />
      <item id="152" url="PageText.aspx?id=152" name="história">
        <item id="435" url="PageText.aspx?id=435" name="antigos reitores" />
        <item id="434" url="PageText.aspx?id=434" name="honoris causa" />
      </item>
      <item id="429" url="PageText.aspx?id=429" name="factos e números" />
      <item id="155" url="" name="as cidades da UA">
        <item id="156" url="PageImage.aspx?id=156" name="aveiro" />
        <item id="157" url="PageText.aspx?id=157" name="águeda" />
        <item id="158" url="PageText.aspx?id=158" name="oliveira de azeméis">
        </item>
      </item>
      <item id="159" url="" name="o campus">
        <item id="431" url="PageText.aspx?id=431" name="apresentação" />
        <item id="160" url="ReadObject.aspx?obj=98" name="mapa do campus (pdf)" />
      </item>
      <item id="299" url="PageGallery.aspx?id=13" name="a ua em fotografia" />
      <item id="446" url="PageText.aspx?id=446" name="a ua digital">
        <item id="447" url="http://uaonline.ua.pt/" name="UAOnline" />
        <item id="448" url="doc" name="bibliotecas da ua" />
        <item id="449" url="http://wsl2.cemed.ua.pt/uoel/estatica/geral/index.asp" name="e-learning" />
        <item id="450" url="http://my.ua.pt" name="my ua" />
        <item id="451" url="http://paco.ua.pt/" name="portal académico" />
        <item id="452" url="http://sinbad.ua.pt" name="sinbad" />
      </item>
      <item id="162" url="" name="legislação geral">
        <item id="432" url="http://legua.ua.pt/textoslegua/conhecimento/universidade%20de%20aveiro/estatutos%20e%20org%E2nica%20da%20ua/normas%20internas/estatutos_ua_versao_integral.aspx" name="estatutos" />
        <item id="433" url="http://legua.ua.pt/textoslegua/conhecimento/universidade%20de%20aveiro/estatutos%20e%20org%E2nica%20da%20ua/normas%20internas/lei_organica_ua.aspx" name="lei orgânica" />
      </item>
      <item id="455" url="PageAgenda.aspx" name="agenda da UA" />
    </item>
    <item id="149" url="" name="organização">
      <item id="150" url="" name="órgãos de governo">
        <item id="130" url="Cursos.aspx" name="reitoria" />
        <item id="145" url="PageText.aspx?id=145" name="assembleia" />
        <item id="146" url="PageText.aspx?id=146" name="senado universitário" />
        <item id="147" url="PageText.aspx?id=147" name="conselho da universidade" />
        <item id="148" url="PageText.aspx?id=148" name="conselho administrativo" />
      </item>
      <item id="164" url="" name="órgãos de coordenação">
        <item id="4552" url="adm" name="administração" />
        <item id="165" url="PageText.aspx?id=165" name="conselho científico" />
        <item id="166" url="PageText.aspx?id=166" name="conselho pedagógico" />
        <item id="255" url="PageText.aspx?id=255" name="inst. de formação superior politécnica" />
        <item id="256" url="ifiu" name="inst. de formação inicial universitária" />
        <item id="257" url="ifpg" name="inst. de formação pós-graduada" />
        <item id="258" url="ii" name="inst. de investigação" />
        <item id="1386" url="cifop" name="formação de professores (cifop)" />
      </item>
      <item id="171" url="" name="serviços">
        <item id="423" url="saa" name="académicos e administrativos" />
        <item id="425" url="sas" name="acção social" />
        <item id="419" url="doc" name="documentação" />
        <item id="424" url="sfp" name="financeiros e património" />
        <item id="418" url="sre" name="relações externas" />
        <item id="420" url="stec" name="técnicos" />
      </item>
      <item id="172" url="" name="gabinetes de apoio">
        <item id="267" url="ajuridica" name="assessoria jurídica" />
        <item id="4725" url="uaedicoes" name="comissão editorial" />
        <item id="436" url="gesp" name="estágios e saídas profissionais" />
        <item id="437" url="gagi" name="gestão de informação" />
        <item id="271" url="pedagogico" name="pedagógico" />
        <item id="438" url="gaqap" name="qualidade, avaliação e procedimentos" />
        <item id="4662" url="drh" name="recursos humanos" />
        <item id="439" url="gri" name="relações internacionais" />
      </item>
      <item id="173" url="" name="outras unidades">
        <item id="441" url="cic" name="centro de informática e comunicações" />
        <item id="442" url="cemed" name="centro multimédia e ensino a distância" />
        <item id="444" url="fabrica" name="fábrica" />
        <item id="445" url="unave" name="formação profissional (unave)" />
        <item id="278" url="fjjm" name="fundação joão jacinto magalhães" />
        <item id="4788" url="grupunave" name="grupunave" />
        <item id="440" url="lca" name="laboratório central de análises" />
        <item id="443" url="uatec" name="transferência de tecnologia (uatec)" />
      </item>
    </item>
    <item id="167" url="" name="departamentos">
      <item id="259" url="PageText.aspx?id=259" name="departamentos e s.a." />
      <item id="260" url="PageText.aspx?id=260" name="escolas politécnicas" />
    </item>
    <item id="168" url="" name="ensino">
      <item id="176" url="PageCourses.aspx?grau=Licenciatura" name="licenciaturas" />
      <item id="202" url="PageCourses.aspx?grau=Licenciatura Bi-etápica" name="licenciaturas bi-etápicas" />
      <item id="177" url="PageCourses.aspx?grau=Mestrado Integrado" name="mestrados integrados" />
      <item id="178" url="PageText.aspx?id=4223" name="mestrados" />
      <item id="179" url="PageText.aspx?id=4224" name="formação especializada" />
      <item id="180" url="PageText.aspx?id=4226" name="doutoramentos" />
      <item id="182" url="PageText.aspx?id=4228" name="formação pós-secundária" />
      <item id="185" url="PageCourses.aspx?grau=Bacharelato" name="bacharelatos" />
    </item>
    <item id="169" url="" name="i&amp;d">
      <item id="187" url="http://uaonline.ua.pt/listagem.asp?pg=1&amp;tipo=8" name="notícias sobre investigação" />
      <item id="287" url="PageText.aspx?id=287" name="unidades de investigação" />
      <item id="288" url="PageText.aspx?id=288" name="laboratórios associados" />
      <item id="190" url="" name="sistemas de suporte">
        <item id="281" url="http://curriculum.ua.pt" name="curriculum@ua" />
        <item id="282" url="http://abc.ua.pt" name="e-abc" />
      </item>
      <item id="298" url="PageText.aspx?id=298" name="planos de formação" />
      <item id="192" url="PageText.aspx?id=453" name="centro de mobilidade de investigadores" />
      <item id="193" url="" name="áreas de doutoramento" />
      <item id="283" url="PageText.aspx?id=283" name="interfaces de apoio">
        <item id="284" url="http://www.grupunave.pt/" name="apoio à propriedade industrial" />
        <item id="285" url="http://ie.web.ua.pt/" name="incubadora de empresas" />
        <item id="286" url="uatec" name="transferência de tecnologia (uatec)" />
      </item>
    </item>
    <item id="170" url="" name="cooperação">
      <item id="195" url="PageText.aspx?id=459" name="divulgação científica">
        <item id="460" url="http://academiadeverao.ua.pt" name="academia de verão" />
        <item id="461" url="fabrica" name="fábrica centro de ciência viva" />
        <item id="462" url="http://microrato.ua.pt" name="micro-rato" />
        <item id="463" url="http://pmate.ua.pt/" name="projecto matemática ensino" />
        <item id="464" url="http://event.ua.pt/semct" name="semana aberta da ciência e tecnologia" />
      </item>
      <item id="196" url="PageText.aspx?id=465" name="com o tecido empresarial">
        <item id="477" url="http://www2.ua.pt/forum3e" name="forum3e" />
        <item id="479" url="gesp" name="estágios e saídas profissionais" />
      </item>
      <item id="197" url="PageText.aspx?id=467" name="promoção cultural">
        <item id="486" url="uaedicoes" name="comissão editorial" />
        <item id="489" url="http://www.orquestradasbeiras.com/" name="orquestra filarmonia das beiras" />
      </item>
      <item id="198" url="PageText.aspx?id=470" name="internacionalização">
        <item id="490" url="http://www.eciu.org/" name="eciu" />
      </item>
      <item id="289" url="PageText.aspx?id=289" name="cooperação para o desenvolvimento" />
      <item id="200" url="PageText.aspx?id=472" name="projectos e programas">
      </item>
      <item id="290" url="PageText.aspx?id=290" name="unidades de interface">
        <item id="291" url="fabrica" name="fábrica de centro de ciência viva" />
        <item id="292" url="fjjm" name="fundacão joão jacinto de magalhães" />
        <item id="293" url="grupunave" name="grupunave" />
        <item id="294" url="http://www.idad.ua.pt" name="inst. do ambiente e desenvolvimento">
        </item>
        <item id="295" url="lca" name="laboratório central de análises " />
        <item id="296" url="unave" name="unave " />
        <item id="747" url="uatec" name="transferência de tecnologia (uatec)" />
      </item>
    </item>
  </item>
  <item id="0.2" url="Default.aspx?lang=EN" name="english">
  </item>
  <item id="0.3" url="Default.aspx?lang=ES" name="español">
  </item>
</menu_list>
```

It is easy to see that the root element is `menu_list` and inside the root there are several `item` elements with attributes. Inside these `item` elements, there can be more `item` elements.

I tried the following as a Schema:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="menu_list"/>
    <xs:complexType name="itemType" >
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="item" type="itemType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But when I open the XML file, it has 101 messages saying something like: `Message   1   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'id'.`.
I already added the right schema in the properties of the XML file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You're close -- just a few changes to make:**

**(1)** Add `type="itemType" to the declaration of`menu_list:

```
<xs:element name="menu_list" type="itemType"/>
```

**(2)** Fix your XML or XSD so that `@id` is typed properly; I'll opt for the XSD:

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
```

**(3)** Finally, if necessary, hint to the XML processor which XSD to use via `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`:

```
<menu_list id="0" name="menu de topo" url=""
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="menu_list.xsd">
```

**Here is your complete XSD with corrections made:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="menu_list" type="itemType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="itemType" >
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="item" type="itemType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="url" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```